# validates_confirmation_of in Rails preventing me from saving a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models

In my User.rb model, I have this line:

validates_confirmation_of :password, :message => "Your passwords should match."

Then when the user signs up, the passwords match, everything is great... until I want to add more information to the user object, then save again.  But running @user.save returns the error that my passwords don't match.  In my signup controller method, I have these lines:

```
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if request.post?
    if !@user.save
      @errors = @user.errors
    else

      # crucial user details:
      @user.salt = [Array.new(6){rand(256).chr}.join].pack("m").chomp 
      @user.password = encrypted_password(@user.password, @user.salt) #hash this
      if !@user.save
        puts "error for some reason in signup"
        puts @user.errors.inspect
      end
```

And upon inspection, @users.errors.inspect prints out:  #["Your passwords should match."]}.  They did, otherwise, it would never have passed the first .save call.  Any advice on what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This fixed it:

validates_confirmation_of :password, :on => :create, :message => "Your passwords should match."